# How does the .NET Installer task chooses which version to install?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created a test pipeline with a .NET Core Installer task like this:

[image: Build task]

Running the task today (2019-11-22), it installs `v2.2.402`:

```
##[section]Starting: Use .Net Core sdk 2.2.x
==============================================================================
Task         : Use .NET Core
Description  : Acquires a specific version of the .NET Core SDK from the internet or the local cache and adds it to the PATH. Use this task to change the version of .NET Core used in subsequent tasks. Additionally provides proxy support.
Version      : 2.0.24
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/AA4xgy0
==============================================================================
Tool to install: .NET Core sdk version 2.2.x.
Found version 2.2.402 in channel 2.2 for user specified version spec: 2.2.x
Version: 2.2.402 was found in cache.
Creating global tool path and pre-pending to PATH.
##[section]Finishing: Use .Net Core sdk 2.2.x
```

According to the [Download .NET Core 2.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) page, SDKs `2.2.402`, `2.2.206` and `2.2.109` (runtime `v2.2.7`) were released on **September 10th 2019**:

[image: .NET Core SDK v2.2.402]

But SDKs `2.2.207` and `2.2.110` (runtime `v2.2.8`) were released on **November 19th 2019**:

[image: .NET Core SDK v2.2.207]

So, acccording to the documentation of the [.NET Core Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops), versions can be given in the following formats:

- `2.x` => Install latest in major version.
- `2.2.x` => Install latest in major and minor version
- `2.2.104` => Install exact version

Why was `v2.2.402` installed? What is the criteria used for choosing the version of the SDK to install when using wildcards such as `2.2.x` or `2.1.x`?

Comment: Please report this as a bug at https://github.com/dotnet/core

Comment: @OmairMajid issue was reported here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/832002/net-core-installer-task-is-not-installing-the-late.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing here, our product group will investigate further. This will wait for some time.Once we have the latest progress, we will notify you in time and synchronize here.Thanks for your patience and understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why was v2.2.402 installed? What is the criteria used for choosing the version of the SDK to install when using wildcards such as 2.2.x or 2.1.x?

Sorry for this late reply, but still hope it can give you any help

This is a known issue on Github:

[.NET Core November Update - 2.1.14, 2.2.8, and 3.0.1](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3848)

IanKemp commented:

> 2.2.7 contained SDK 2.2.402 for VS 2019 v16.2, but **this release has no SDK for 16.2 only for 16.0**. Does that mean SDK 2.2.402 is the latest
>   and that if we already have it, we don't need SDK 2.2.207 from 2.2.8

Compare the release note `v2.2.8` and `v2.2.7`:

[image]

So, the latest SDK version does not support the latest Visual Studio version, that may the reason why we still get the version `v2.2.402` by that task.

The version that supports `16.2` should be released soon. By then we can use this task to get version `2.2.207`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, things now make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The version in Use .Net Core task or .Net Core Installer task are picked using [semantic versioning 2.0](https://semver.org/).

Hence, the highest version number is picked which in case of 2.2.207 and 2.2.402 is 2.2.402

Comment: Yes I had the impression that the task was using semantic versioning to pick up the version of the SDK, but the versioning of the .NET Core SDK is still confusing to me. Shouldn't the PATCH number be incremented according to the semantic versioning?

Comment: The problem is that the .NET Core Installer task is not picking up the latest version of the SDK. I'm wondering if the task should use the **runtime version** instead of the **SDK version** to pick up the latest SDK?